# how to print php as html text

Tags: php, html, printing

please, how to print php as html text ?

for example:

i have this php line

```
if(defined('LOAD_VARS') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)
```

i want to print it as html text

so output will be

```
if(defined('LOAD_VARS') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)
```

i have tried this

```
<textarea style="width:600px; height:30px;">if(defined('LOAD_VARS') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)</textarea>
```

but it doesn't work and show error

how i can do that please ?

how

Comment: define *it doesn't work* and show us given error

Comment: May be you just forgot to close PHP tag before `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but here goes:

Close the PHP tag before outputting anything, or simply use `print()` or `echo`.

**Example 1:**

```
<?php
print('if(defined(\'LOAD_VARS\') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)');
?>
```

**Example 2**

```
<?php
// Your code that you want to be run.
?>

<pre>if(defined('LOAD_VARS') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/highlight-string)

```
$source = "if(defined('LOAD_VARS') AND LOAD_VARS === TRUE)";
echo highlight_string($source, true);
```